# Unable to sign AAB file using 'r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1' in github action workflow

Tags: android, apk, github-actions, android-app-signing

I am getting the following error when signing the APK in Github workflow.

### Below are some logs details from github workflow:

> Run r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1 with:

> releaseDirectory: app/release signingKeyBase64: ***

> alias: ***

> keyStorePassword: ***

> keyPassword: ***

> env: JAVA_HOME_8.0.275_x64:
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64 JAVA_HOME:
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64 JAVA_HOME_8_0_275_X64:
> /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64 BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION: 30.0.2

> Preparing to sign key @ app/release with signing key

> **/opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64/bin/jarsigner -keystore app/release/signingKey.jks -storepass *** -keypass ***
> app/release/app-release.aab *****

This is the error part:
jarsigner: unable to sign jar:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected
> 38206 but got 38984 bytes) Error: The process
> '/opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.275/x64/bin/jarsigner' failed with exit
> code 1

I believe it's very specific to jar signer, ( I tried with the answer it fix the problem)

Update: This has happening to me as well.

Comment: Did you try to prepare the key with openssl? openssl base64 < some_signing_key.jks | tr -d '\n' | tee some_signing_key.jks.base64.txt github.com/r0adkll/sign-android-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your KeyStore, Alias, KeyStore Password and Key Password in the secret section inside GitHub settings.

- SIGNING_KEY — base64 text of your Keystore file
- ALIAS — your alias name
- KEY_STORE_PASSWORD — password of your Keystore
- KEY_PASSWORD — your key password

```html
- name: Sign AAB
  id: sign
  uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
  with:
    releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/bundle/release
    signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY }}
    alias: ${{ secrets.ALIAS }}
    keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD }}
    keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}
```

[r0adkll/sign-android-release](https://github.com/r0adkll/sign-android-release)

Comment: Its already there in github secrets, and when it's building it retrieve the correction values.

Comment: Please make sure you release directory is correctly pointed to the directory of release build. I hope your release directory is wrong.

Comment: that is pointing to correct directory, there is no issue with directory or any other secrets params.